# "Save Edits" button for a new nomination should not immediately post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, moderator-election

When one nominates oneself for a moderator election, one is given a modified version of the usual post interface: there's a text view and a preview below it, and one button that says:

[image: "Save Edits" button]

Which doesn't, to me at least, clearly indicate that my brand-new nomination is going to be posted as soon as I hit it. I *suspected* that it would, since it's basically the same as the tag wiki creation interface, but it could be more explicit.

Until the nomination has been made public the first time, it would be preferable that the button's title reflect its immediate effect.

(My title recommendation would be <kbd>SUBMIT TO MERCILESS PUBLIC SCRUTINY</kbd>, but I'll leave the final wording up to the UX experts, of course.)

Comment: It is possible to edit once you submit, right?

Comment: I'm sure that there are a lot of other missing features that concern more than 10 people every year.

Comment: *"SUBMIT TO MERCILESS PUBLIC SCRUTINY"*. Hmm. A bit wordy.

Comment: @Gimby wordy indeed, but so accurate!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre True, but how much effort does it really take to change the text on a button? It's not like this'll halt development for a month.

Comment: @Aran-Fey so why didn't they change the text of picture insertion to add "no pictures of code please" because that's a cheap change, everyone agrees, but not done...

Comment: Not a severity-1 issue, @Jean-FrançoisFabre, sure, but worth filing.

Comment: Maybe the button can be changed to `Submit and nominate` or `Submit nomination`

Comment: Regardless of how many people are affected, it makes no sense to have a button that does not do what it says (well, technically, it does... but let's not split hairs)...

Comment: Maybe the button can be changed to "There are already 11 candidates, sorry" :)

Comment: I'd say it's rather a [tag:bug] than a [tag:feature-request]

Comment: Definitely a usability issue and one with potentially "embarassing" consequences; shouldn't be hard to make a button label accurately describe what the button does

Comment: I'm kind of astonished at the number of upvotes here; to re-iterate my comment under the deleted answer, this is really a fairly minor issue in my mind.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yeah well, I'm kind of inclined to upvote things that don't deal with the usual Stack Overflow angst.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, fine, the submit button will now read "Post your nomination" when you haven't yet posted it.